# Random background color script only changes background color of one out of three tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js script which changes the background color of 3 a tags every time someone refreshes the page. Problem is that it only changes the background color on one out of the 3 a tags.

```js
function random_bg_color() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
 console.log(bgColor);

    document.getElementById("rand-c").style.background = bgColor;
    document.getElementById("rand-c").style.border = bgColor;
    }

random_bg_color();
```

```css
a {
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="rand-c">1st tag</a>
<a href="" id="rand-c">2nd tag</a>
<a href="" id="rand-c">3rd tag</a>
```

Comment: ID should be unique. In your case it will target only the first appearance

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai do you know a work around?

Comment: I have given my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class` instead of `id` and then get the target elements using `getElementsByClassName("rand-c")`. This will gives you the entire set and need to loop it for applying styles to them like below.

```js
function random_bg_color() { 
    var i;
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("rand-c");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
      arr[i].style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
      arr[i].style.border = bgColor;
   }
 }

random_bg_color();
```

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="rand-c">1st tag</a>
<a href="" class="rand-c">2nd tag</a>
<a href="" class="rand-c">3rd tag</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById()` returns the first element. Use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead and iterate over the results. Such as;

```
var tags = document.querySelectorAll("#rand-c");

for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
{ 
    tags[i].style.background = bgColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id as a attribute in  anchor tag .
because, id refer the first tag only it is a  unique identifier. so use class

Answer (score 0):

Generally, id should be unique throughout the DOM. As @Lece hinted above, getElementById() will return the first matching element by default. I suggest you use class then use getElementByClassName and set the style.

Answer (score 0):

you html code have error,id can not repeat